# How to list out NextJS router param array

Tags: javascript, arrays, next.js

I have a `NextJS` catch all route which pulls in

```
import { useRouter} from 'next/router'
```

And retrieves all the parameters:

```
const { params = [] } = router.query
```

If I log the `params` value I see all the URL path elements in the console.

I would like to repeat out all the `params` values in an unordered list:

```
return <ul>
  {params.map((param) => {
    <li>{param}</li>
  })}
</ul>
```

But this outputs nothing. There are no elements displayed.

How can I get this to display the list?

Comment: Where do you want to output it in the terminal (console.log) or in the UI?

Comment: An unordered list on the page. `console.log(params)` prints out just fine to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With curly braces you will have to write the return keyword too.

```
return <ul>
  {params.map((param) => {
    return (<li>{param}</li>);
  })}
</ul>
```

This is how [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax) work in JS.

With the current code, there is no return statement basically. So by [default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#description) `undefined` is returned and nothing is rendered  :

```
return <ul>
  {params.map((param) => {
    <li>{param}</li>
    //No return statement  
})}
</ul>
```

For short : You can remove the curly braces.

```
return <ul>
  {params.map((param) => <li>{param}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with your `.map` function.
Try doing this instead:

```
return params.map((param) => param);
```

This will just print your params together in a single line. You can improvise the format in which you would actually want it.

Comment: I want each `param` wrapped in a `<li>...</li>` item, not just dumped out to the page, like the `console.log()` does.